# RDLC: Display a list with multiple, fixed columns and variable rows

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reportviewer, rdlc

I am developing a report using RDLC (Winforms version) in VS 2010. Part of the report is listing a series of images (with text captions). The list of images is of variable length. I would like to conserve real-estate on the report by displaying two images per "row" in the list of images.

For example, if the number of images is 2, I would display:

A B

If there are 3 images:

A B
C

If there are 5 images:

A B

C D

E

... and so on.

I have seen this (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrishays/archive/2004/07/23/horizontaltables.aspx) blog, but it is for a fixed number of rows, which does not apply in this case. I want the list to grow, first left-to-right, but increasing in rows for every two images (as shown above).

Is there any way to accomplish this with RDLC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a hack that answers my own question. Basically, you create as many vertical lists as you need columns (in my case: 2) and then set conditional visibility for each list so that they only show a subset of the items in their query.

Look at this thread: http://forums.asp.net/t/1373432.aspx

Comment: Old post I know, but that link helped a lot. Thanks! Do you happen to know the property for the list that puts the spaces between items? I'm putting images in my lists and the 2nd and 3rd column are all shifted down a bit. Padding/Margins does not do it. Inspecting the XML does not shed any light. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for the link it helps me to solve my problem. A bit tricky, but it's better than nothing)